How I can Get Response Data From Client API endpoint on Mirth and Send that to one of My data base using Mirth
Can anyone please advise me how I can resolve this below issue on Mirth :
I have an API end-point of One Client example: (Https://xyzclient)  and I have to get data from this API and send that to one of my Database.
What I am doing is I'm putting the details of this API in the HTTP sender of the destination connector and by this I am getting the API response values in Response section of Destination connector but not sure how I can exclude value from there and send to another destination or My DataBase and channel.
Any Response will be highly appreciable.
What I am doing is I'm putting the details of this API in the HTTP sender of the destination connector and by this I am getting the API response values in Response section of Destination connector but not sure how I can exclude value from there and send to another destination or My DataBase and channel.

I think what you may be looking for is the response transformer.
While on the Destinations tab, in the "Channel Tasks" pane to the left, click "Edit Response".
Then you can gain access to the response value with something like
msg['nameOfYourResponseValue'];

So a good way to store that value to use later, you would be something like
channelMap.put('returnedvalue',msg['nameOfYourResponseValue']); 

You can then use either channelMap.get('returnedvalue') from within javascript, or the drag and drop from the UI to write out to your database.

I got the response and Stored them in Variable but issue is when I am connecting mirth with my RDS Database its throwing Error : Method failed: HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
com.mirth.connect.client.core.ClientException: Method failed: HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
at com.mirth.connect.client.core.ServerConnection.handleResponse(ServerConnection.java:5     And   // I have added the Driver for PostgreSQL into mirth Lib folder but still unable to connect with DB.
